# XGBoost results changing when one row is removed

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, xgboost

I have a training dataset of 2,600 rows and 26 columns.

I trained an XGBoost (1.3.1) Classification model using the data and evaluated it using a test set of c. 800 rows.

Whilst experimenting I found that although the model has stable results when being re-run, if I remove just 1 row (chosen at random) from the dataset the individual row prediction probabilities change by up to 15%.

I can't understand why removing 1 of 2,600 rows results in such considerable changes in the model!

Parameters:

```
{'learning_rate': 0.05, \
 'n_estimators': 66, \
 'max_depth': 6, \
 'subsample': 1, \
 'min_child_weight': 1, \
 'colsample_bytree': 1, \
 'gamma': 0.5, \
 'reg_alpha': 0.001, \
 'nthread': 1, \
 'seed': 11}
```

Comment: How did you asses that your model is stable? The stability of the model is looked through tests like, move one of your parameter left or right by a little and look at the results for exemple. What type of results move by 15% ? The score or the prediction? What is the score difference between the train and the test?

Comment: If that is the case then I would say your model is definitely not stable, it probably does not converge suitably.

Comment: @minattosama sorry, edited to make it clearer. What I mean by results moving is that the individual prediction probabilities are changing by up to 15%. So for instance, train with the full dataset and predict the probability of the first row of the test set and get a value such as 60%. Repeat with 1 row randomly deleted and the same row gets a predicted probability of 70%. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: It makes a little more sense. However it doesn't respond the questions that I asked. How did  you asses your stability ? It is normal to have results like that if your model is not stable. Split in train test and check the error score in those. This is the first check up that you should do before running any other hyperparameter or anything else.

Comment: The training set has performance of c. 67% and test set of c. 65% - although the data is time dependent so I can't run cross-validation properly as the test set must always be the latest data.

Answer (score 0):

Tree-based models are very unstable so it is expected to see totally different tree geometries when changed only a single point but the predictive performance shouldn't be that different if the dataset is balanced.

I would recommend running a proper validation schema to see the uncertainty around model performance instead of just looking at a simple train-test split.

Comment: Please refrain of posting answears without getting the full picture of the question. Use comments instead. I know that you need 50 rep for comments however we should respect the guidelines. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the response!

The reason I need stability in the individual outputs is because they are used as an input to a meta model. 

Currently I take the training dataset, split it into sets (usually around 100 in size each). I then holdout one set and use the remaining to train the model and then predict the holdout values. I repeat this until the whole train set has a heldout predicted value. This way I can use this data as an input into the meta model without worrying about stacking overfitting. Having the values vary so much obviously impacts this!